# How to create directories on the server where ansible is running

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am new to Ansible and I am trying to create an Ansible Playbook, which makes a backup of directories from different hosts to the control server (which is the same machine where Ansible is invoked).

I would like to create directories on the *control server* first and then do a synchronize (`ansible.posix.synchronize`) or copy (`ansible.builtin.copy`, `ansible.builtin.fetch`) command to copy all the directories from all hosts to the control server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**To create a local directory**:

```
- name: Create local directory
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /path/to/new/directory
    state: directory
  register: local_dir
  delegate_to: localhost
```

See [ansible.builtin.file – Manage files and file properties](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html) for details on the `ansible.builtin.file` module.

The path can be relative or absolute.

The key to doing it on the Ansible controller is the last line (`delegate_to: localhost`).

For more information see [Delegation, Rolling Updates, and Local Actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html).

---

**For copying data** from the remote to the local machine, use the `ansible.posix.synchronize` module.

See [ansible.posix.synchronize – A wrapper around rsync to make common tasks in your playbooks quick and easy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) for details.

By default, it will copy from local to remote (default `mode: push`), but you can use `mode: pull` to reverse this.

**Note:** You need to create the base directory first locally (`dest: "{{ local_dir.path }}"`), but the `synchronize` module will create the necessary directories beneath it (standard `rsync(1)` functionality).

---

Finally, I'll include below my list of Ansible introductory videos and other resources I came across. The star ratings are my personal opinion of the resources. Keep in mind that a lot has changed in Ansible in the last 2-3 years.

- linda.com free trial
- [linuxacademy.com](https://linuxacademy.com/)
- YouTube: [Ansible - an absolute basic overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfoAb50Br94) ★★★★
- YouTube: Ansible - A Beginner's Tutorial ★★★ parts [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icR-df2Olm8) [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRZA9ymZXn0) [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBiueVhDg1Q) [4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeGDc7rCK_0) [5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Z-evEafMvY)
- YouTube: [What Is Ansible?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgQ3rHFTM4E) ★★
- YouTube: [Ansible Playbook Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCQpaTTTv98) ★★
- ansible.com: [Quick Start video](https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/qrqfj371b6) ★★★★★
- YouTube: [Ansible Bootstrap Playbook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7pw7z00CeU) ★★★★★
- YouTube: [Network Automation using Ansible and Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYEVjKvMKqU) (2015) ★★★
- [How to Use Ansible: A Reference Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ansible-cheat-sheet-guide)
- [10 Things you should start using in your Ansible Playbook](https://medium.com/@abhijeet.kamble619/10-things-you-should-start-using-in-your-ansible-playbook-808daff76b65)

I hope you enjoy learning about Ansible. I certainly have!

Comment: The ansible.posix.synchronize command supports `delegate_to` as well.